# Is there an efficient way to load a large bibtex (37000 bibtex entries) file in python?

Tags: python, performance, bibtex

In my python application, I load about 37'000 BibTeX entries.

The following chunk of code loads the .txt file as bibtex file, but it takes a lot of time to load the file contents for further processing. Is there a way do it more efficiently?

```
with open('/home/usr/Downloads/bibtexFile.txt') as bibtex_file:
    bibtex_str = bibtex_file.read()

bib_database = bibtexparser.loads(bibtex_str)
```

Comment: You should try using `bibtexparser.load(bibtex_file)` on the file object directly

Comment: have you tried biblib? it is pure python.

Comment: @MEdwin Using biblib produces this error: "An error occurred while starting the kernel"

Comment: check your version you installed, could it be an old version?

Comment: hi @ftTomAndJerry, I have tried installed biblib myself. I installed biblib ==0.1.3 and I am using it right now and everything works seemlessly. I can share my code if you want. Other alternatives if you are stuck:  BabyBib,Pybtex, BibtexParser, Pybliographer.

Comment: @MEdwin Yes, please. If you can share the code in answer (if you think an answer is appropriate for this question), it will be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using the `biblib ==0.1.3`. The file `stats.bib` contains uniquely formated bibtex entries.

```
from pybtex.database.input import bibtex
parser = bibtex.Parser()
bib_data = parser.parse_file('stats.bib')
print (bib_data.entries)
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. It works far better.
With bibtexparser, it took about 5 minutes to load the big data, 
while with biblib it loaded the file in 0:00:15.584566 (about 15 sec)

Comment: However, this produces an error 

if 'doi' in bib_database.entries[i]:

  File "/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pybtex/utils.py", line 161, in __getitem__
    return self._dict[key.lower()]

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: i am glad it works. I will like to investigate that error. Could it be that the bib files has stored the doi as integers?

Comment: DOI is an alphanumeric value. So it should not be stored as an integer. I have uploaded the file here. May be you can have a look: https://a.uguu.se/wnVTbOTaqqmN.txt

Comment: sorry, I cant download files in my work, but you can open the .bib file (a text reader will do, notepad, notepad++ etc). I will show you how the format looks below. doi should be in  a something like  {10.1002/cpe.4460} or  {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jpdc.2018.04.017}.

Comment: Yes, that is the DOI with numbers, special characters and small alphabets.

Comment: The part when I try to access the DOI field using this chunk of code,

        if bib_data.entries[i]['doi'].startswith('http'):
            bib_data.entries[i]['doi'] = bib_data.entries[i]['doi'][19:]

Comment: aha... I get you now. You seem to be trying to re-assign an integer to bib_data.entries[i]['doi'] that is why. you might want to create a different variable to store each entry.

Comment: I have created a new answer to help push the bibtex entries into a numpy dataframe.

Comment: Even after assigning the modified string to a new variable, it gives the same error.

Comment: yes, you are right, you seems to be looping through bibdata.entries with an integer.

Comment: You should rather do "for bib_id in bib_data.entries:" in the loop is bib_id is unique.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me, but I also used this article (https://docs.pybtex.org/api/parsing.html) to understand how to iterate through this object type: <class 'pybtex.database.BibliographyData'>

Comment: this lib is no longer updated... pls do not use.

Answer (score 1):

This code will help you push the content of the bib into a dataframe:

```
from pybtex.database.input import bibtex

#open a bibtex file
parser = bibtex.Parser()
bibdata = parser.parse_file("stats.bib")
bibkeys=bibdata.entries.keys()
bibarray= []

for bib_id in bibdata.entries:
     b = bibdata.entries[bib_id].fields
     if b["year"] is None: 
        dyear='NA'
        print dyear
     else: 
        dyear=b["year"]

     if b.get("journal"):
       djournal=b["journal"]
     else: 
       djournal='NA'  

     if b.get("booktitle"):
       dbooktitle=b["booktitle"]
     else: 
       dbooktitle='NA'      

     d = {
            'bib_id' : bib_id,  # some formula for obtaining values
            'Title' : b["title"],
            'Year' : dyear,
            'Journal' : djournal,
            'Book Title' : dbooktitle
            }
     bibarray.append(d)

bibdataset = pd.DataFrame(bibarray)
```